# How to show Plot Legends?

Tags: plotting, legending

How do I make the PlotLegends works in the codes below? I had tried the "Expressions" option and other string options. Only the Ture option will give one legend but not all legends.

```
term = Table[Exp[3*Exp[v] - 3 - k*v] /. v -> Log[n*k/3], {n, 0.7, 1.3, 0.3}]
Plot[term, {k, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"0.7", "1", "1.3"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate@term, {k, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> {"0.7", "1", "1.3"}]
```

[image]